# WSO2 CEP 4.1.0 distributed mode with Storm 0.10.0

Tags: wso2, apache-storm, wso2-cep

Can WSO2 CEP 4.1.0 work with Storm 0.10.0?

I get the following error, when try to use WSO2 CEP 4.1.0 with Storm 0.10.0 (Hortonworks HDP 2.4)

Can I apply a solution from https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/8916/submitting-a-topology-to-strom-cluster-required-fi.html to the WSO2 CEP? How I can?

```
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.storm.StormTopologyManager} -  TopologySubmitterJob:97, Retrying to submit topology 'ExecutionPlan[-1234]' in 10000 ms
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.storm.StormTopologyManager} -  TopologySubmitterJob:97, Error connecting to storm when trying to check whether topology 'ExecutionPlan[-1234]' exist
org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.exception.ServerUnavailableException: Error connecting to storm when trying to check whether topology 'ExecutionPlan[-1234]' exist
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.storm.StormTopologyManager$TopologySubmitter.isTopologyExist(StormTopologyManager.java:283)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.storm.StormTopologyManager$TopologySubmitter.run(StormTopologyManager.java:200)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TProtocolException: **Required field 'nimbus_uptime_secs' is unset!** Struct:ClusterSummary(supervisors:[SupervisorSummary(host:m347hdp1.nova.otp.int, uptime_secs:4932482, num_workers:2, num_used_workers:0, supervisor_id:dd4256ff-b2cd-4873-bac6-d5488f505ca1), SupervisorSummary(host:m348hdp2.nova.otp.int, uptime_secs:4932472, num_workers:2, num_used_workers:0, supervisor_id:b50dab9a-44e4-4888-b370-72c0c7d7c16c)], nimbus_uptime_secs:0, topologies:[])
        at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary.validate(ClusterSummary.java:587)
        at backtype.storm.generated.ClusterSummary.read(ClusterSummary.java:514)
        at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$getClusterInfo_result.read(Nimbus.java:10665)
        at org.apache.thrift7.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.recv_getClusterInfo(Nimbus.java:468)
        at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.getClusterInfo(Nimbus.java:456)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.storm.StormTopologyManager$TopologySubmitter.isTopologyExist(StormTopologyManager.java:275)
        ... 2 more
```

Comment: CEP 4.1.0 does not support 0.10.0 of storm. This will be updated in the next release.

Comment: @SajithEshan When can we expect the release of WSO2 CEP 4.2.0?

Comment: @SajithEshan
WSO2 CEP 4.2.0 has released.
Does CEP 4.2.0 support Storm 0.10.0?

Comment: it supports storm 0.10.x